# Reducing whitespace after linebreaks in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following snippet

```
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement = \&]
    x_j \arrow[r, mapsto] \& \frac{x_j}{x_i} \\
    A(Y_i) \arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\sim"] \& (S(Y)_{x_i})^0 \\
    \begin{cases}
        1 & i = j\\
        x_j & i \neq j
    \end{cases} \& x_j \arrow[l, mapsto] 
\end{tikzcd}
```

which gives the following image: [image]

I'm not a fan of the large breaks after each line; is there any way to remove them?

Comment: Change the value of  `row sep`. See the possible predefined values p.6 of the documentation

Comment: That worked, thanks! If you wanna post this is an answer, e.g. for search engines, then I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's necessary, as I'm pretty sure there are already similar answered questions (albeit I don't know where).

Comment: Indeed, there are many questions whose solution was to alter the `row sep` or the `column sep` to get longer or shorter arrows. While OP doesn't use vertical arrows in this case, it's the same underlying mechanic. That being said, it might better to split these in three separate diagrams …